# My code wrongfully downloads a CSV file from an URL with Python

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib

I created some code to download a CSV file from an URL. The code downloads the HTML code of the link, but when I copy the url that I created in a browser it works, but it does not in the code.

I tried os, response, and urllib, but all these options provided the same result.

This is the link that I ultimately want to download as CSV:
https://www.ishares.com/uk/individual/en/products/251567/ishares-asia-pacific-dividend-ucits-etf/1506575576011.ajax?fileType=csv&fileName=IAPD_holdings&dataType=fund

```py
import requests
#this is the url where the csv is
url='https://www.ishares.com/uk/individual/en/products/251567/ishares-asia-pacific-dividend-ucits-etf?switchLocale=y&siteEntryPassthrough=true'
r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
response = requests.get(url)
if response.status_code == 200:
    print("Success")
else:
    print("Failure")

#find the url for the CSV
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content,'lxml')
for i in soup.find_all('a',{'class':"icon-xls-export"}):
    print(i.get('href'))

# I get two types of files, one CSV and the other xls. 
link_list=[]
for i in soup.find_all('a', {'class':"icon-xls-export"}):
    link_list.append(i.get('href'))

# I create the link with the CSV
url_csv = "https://www.ishares.com//"+link_list[0]
response_csv = requests.get(url_csv)
if response_csv.status_code == 200:
    print("Success")
else:
    print("Failure")

#Here I want to download the file
import urllib.request
with urllib.request.urlopen(url_csv) as holdings1, open('dataset.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write(holdings1.read().decode())
```

I would like to get the CSV data downloaded.

Comment: What is the actual output now?

Comment: page may use some JavaScript and browser may not have problem to download it. requests/beautifulsoup can't run JavaScript and it can't download. OR page checks cookies, headers, etc before it sends file. If your script doesn't use these headers, cookies then it can't download it.

Comment: It is always good to use `requests.Session()` and at least set correct value fo header `User-Agent`.

Comment: why don't use use `response_csv.read()` to get it ? You don't need `urllib.request` for this. And write it in bytes mode `wb` without decoding.

Comment: if you get HTML in dataset.csv then rename it to .html and open in browser to see if there is some useful information. Maybe there is another link to finall csv file - and maybe it uses javascript to redirect to this url so web browser has no problem to get it but script has problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It needs cookies to work correctly

I use `requests.Session()` to get and keep cookies automatically.

And I write in file `response_csv.content` because I already have it after second requests - so I don't have to make another requests. And because using `urllib.request` I will create requests without cookies and it may not works.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = requests.Session()

url='https://www.ishares.com/uk/individual/en/products/251567/ishares-asia-pacific-dividend-ucits-etf?switchLocale=y&siteEntryPassthrough=true'

response = s.get(url, allow_redirects=True)

if response.status_code == 200:
    print("Success")
else:
    print("Failure")

#find the url for the CSV
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content,'lxml')

for i in soup.find_all('a',{'class':"icon-xls-export"}):
    print(i.get('href'))

# I get two types of files, one CSV and the other xls. 
link_list=[]
for i in soup.find_all('a', {'class':"icon-xls-export"}):
    link_list.append(i.get('href'))

# I create the link with the CSV
url_csv = "https://www.ishares.com//"+link_list[0]

response_csv = s.get(url_csv)

if response_csv.status_code == 200:
    print("Success")
    f = open('dataset.csv', 'wb')
    f.write(response_csv.content)
    f.close()
else:
    print("Failure")
```